# problems with reusing of a variable in java

Tags: java, reference, arraylist, reusability, deep-copy

I got some problem with reference assignment in java.
Let me explain: in my code, i'm using an ArrayList of BooleanWrap (a home made class of boolean) which will be later assigned as a value in a HashMap (there is a for cycle which update the values of this ArrayList until a condition is verified).
Something like this:

```
 ArrayList<BooleanWrap> temp=new ArrayList <BooleanWrap>(48);

 //cycle: operations to fill the ArrayList, then a condition is satisfied

 hashMap.put(index, temp);
```

After that, I have to reuse the temp variable, so I need to reinitialize it. I do it with the following instructions:

```
for(BooleanWrap bool: temp){
    bool.set(false);
  }
```

There comes my problem: assigning temp as a value of the hashMap will save only the reference of the variable, not the actual value.
So, reinitializing temp cause also the updating inside the hashmap (in this case, setting everything false).
Now, I think that even with clone() method I should get the same result (cause it produces a shallow copy of the ArrayList).
Is there a way to reuse the same variable temp in my cycle without assign later the reference of it to the hashmap?
Actually I can do it with a method which creates a deep copy of the arraylist:

```
public static ArrayList<BooleanWrap> deepcopy(ArrayList<BooleanWrap> original){

  ArrayList<BooleanWrap> copy=new ArrayList<BooleanWrap>(48);
  for(BooleanWrap bool: original)
      copy.add(new BooleanWrap (bool.get()));

  return copy;

}
```

but I need something done inline, without any other methods and as shorter as it can be.

Any advice/suggestion/insult?

Comment: Boolean already exists in Java; there's no need for a custom boolean wrapper. Also, I don't understand why you need to re-use temp. Why not use a new variable? Alternatively, why not just assign a new instance of `ArrayList` to temp? I'm sure you have good reasons, but I can't figure them out based on your question.

Comment: i need to reuse temp because in my cycle i don't know how many times i'm going to put it in my hashmap: doing it programmatically, i can't create a new single arraylist object for every hashmap.put. I'm surely missing somthing =| however, i tried to assign a new instance of arraylist to temp but after that, i getting all of the arraylist in hashmap full of false values except for the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that, I have to reuse the temp variable, so I need to
>   reinitialize it. I do it with the following instructions:
>       for(BooleanWrap bool: temp)
>        {    bool.set(false);  }

That does not re-initialize the temp variable.  That re-initializes the *contents* of your temp variable.  to re-initialize the temp variable your code would look like

```
ArrayList<BooleanWrap> temp=new ArrayList <BooleanWrap>(48); 
//cycle: operations to fill the ArrayList, then a condition is satisfied 

hashMap.put(index, temp);

//After that, I have to reuse the temp variable, so I need to reinitialize it. 
// I do it with the following instructions:

temp = new ArrayList <BooleanWrap>(48); 
//cycle: operations to fill the ArrayList
```

Comment: i followed your advice, thanks. obviously I had to recreate subsequently every item in the array list (a for cicle: temp.add(i, new Boolean(false) ). Don't think there's another way to instantiate the new 48 Booleans with less instructions...am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is *not* about *variables*. It is about *objects* and *mutations* upon them.

So **create a new object as needed**. The "issue" is that the original *object* stored in the HashMap is *being mutated*.

Avoiding re-use of variables, however, can (often does?) make code much more maintainable and understandable.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Using a BooleanWRap is very inefficient, even a Boolean would be inefficient.

Instead I suggest you use a BitSet.

```
BitSet temp = new BitSet(48);

//cycle: operations to fill the ArrayList, then a condition is satisfied

hashMap.put(index, temp);

// to create a new BitSet...
temp = new BitSet(48);
```